# get 25% of any given value angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

considering that I have a model that could contain any value from time to time. Here is the value

```
$scope.getTotalValue could be 100, 200 or even 6000.
```

Now I want to calculate the actual 25% of the value in the getTotalValue model

```
$scope.calculatePercentage = (25/100)*(1/$scope.getTotalValue)
```

My challenge with this is that is not giving me the actual percentage of 25 as the result begins with 0.

Comment: You should not have `1/` in front of `$scope.getTotalValue`

Comment: what should it be

Comment: Just `$scope.getTotalValue`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fixed percentage, like 25%, just multiply your value by 0.25:

```
$scope.calculatePercentage = $scope.getTotalValue * 0.25;
```

That is `25 / 100`, or 25 *per cent* (that means, by one hundred).

Answer (score 0):

in this way, you can calculate the percentage of a given number:

```
$scope.getTotalValue = 100;
$scope.calculatePercentage = (($scope.getTotalValue/100)*25)

console.log($scope.calculatePercentage)
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is multiply the particular value by `0.25`. Let me tell you why... `25% of something` is the same as `25/100 of something`, which is nothing but `0.25 of something.`

Hence, the code required to get `25%` of the `$scope.getTotalValue` would be:

```
$scope.calculatePercentage = $scope.getTotalValue * 0.25;
```

That should do. Hope this helps.